# Can we have a dense layer between Conv layers in 1D CNN Architecture?

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network, classification, prediction

I have a question regarding the one-dimensional convolutional neural network 1D CNN.
Can we have a dense layer between Conv layers in the architecture? just like what I have done in the following example:
Note: It is working correctly with CSV files for classification problems.

```
    model = Sequential()
    # First Convolusional Layer
    model.add(Conv1D(128, 5, input_shape=(20,1), strides=2, padding='same'))
    model.add(Dense(256, activation="relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D())
    
    # Second Convolusional Layer
    model.add(Conv1D(128, 3, strides=1, padding='same'))
    model.add(Dense(64, activation="relu"))
    model.add(MaxPooling1D())
    
    # Passing to Fully Connected Layers
    model.add(Flatten())
    model.add(Dense(32, activation = 'relu'))
    #model.add(Dropout(0.02))
    # Output Layer
    model.add(Dense(2, activation = 'sigmoid'))
    
    # Model Compilation
    model.compile(loss = 'sparse_categorical_crossentropy', 
    optimizer = "adam", metrics = ['accuracy'])
    
    # Summary of The Model
    model.summary()
```

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, that you can certainly do. It is not usual at all and not very advisable from a theoretical perspective but it is possible.

**why is it not advisable? (theory)** With convolutions one tries to capture *spatial* features (i.e. information). Values next to each other should have an influence but values far away from this point (in time -- in the case of time series data) should have less influence. That is the whole idea of CNNs. To a fully connected NN the order in which the input is presented to it is not important. It looks at all inputs at the same time since it is equally connected to all. So you loose spatial information. BTW, that is also the reason why it is plausible to do a global pooling before feeding the output of the CNN-part of a model to the fully-connected part of a model (i.e. the dense layers).

Now if you do convolution, you care about spatial information. If you then apply a dense layer, you kind of say "I cared enough about the spatial info". If you then apply convolution again on the output vector of a dense layer it becomes totally irrational.

**feasibility**
Nonetheless, such a network would be feasible. You would just need to make sure that the dense layer outputs a vector (or matrix) again, on which you can apply convolution.

However, **your code** lacks of a proper adapter from the output of the convolution layer to the dense layer. You should apply some type of *global pooling* operation to create a vector that serves as an input to the dense layer. That would also save you the `Flatten()` step. Again, it should work your way anyway. It is just about style since now your are sending mixed signals: flatten should concatenate all spatial layers but the NN ignores spatial information...

I don't get the point of applying `MaxPooling1D´ after the` Dense`-layer. One could simply reduce the number of outputs of the` Dense`-layer. And you definitely don't need a second` Flatten`after a`Dense`-layer as it returns a vector by definition (and pooling won't add a dimension to it)